# Access disk1 of RAID 1 as regular disk on different computer

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-1, lacie

Im using a Lacie 2TB DAS that's configured as a RAID 1. Basically, disk0 is mirrored to disk1. By the time it goes full and I removed both disks from the bay, could I access them on to different computers just as regular disk?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to try it - the answer will depend on the RAID card, but it is very often possible (but not really adviseable, as there will most likely be RAID metadata on the disks)

Comment: This is because I plan to have disk0 on-site and disk1 off-site (disaster and recovery strategy). Does this mean that in order for me to access my files is I have to have both disks on-hand? Can't they stand alone as regular disk? If not, then what's the purpose of having it as Raid, aside from mirroring, if it can't stand on its own when I lose either one of the disk?

Comment: As I said, it may or may not work - the purpose of RAID is to reduce the risks associated with disk failure. Seasoned admins know to have a spare identical RAID card in case the primary fails.  RAID is not the same thing as backup, and you really don't want to be continually rebuilding your array.  RAID 1 can stand on its own if you loose 1 disk - but not is not guaranteed o work on a different controller. Depending on your usage case, you might want to look at doing snapshots and copying those and/or network RAID (ala DRBD or MARS), or a distributed filesystem like glusterfs, or...

Comment: even something like ZFS and streaming or own/nextcloud.

Comment: As an aside, if you use software RAID (or fake raid in Windows)it can be read in other systems and is more-or-less controller agnostic. Still, it's RAID, not backup.

Comment: For the enclosure im using, its hardware based. Just a switch could trigger on it. So it seems like I have to go with this strategy? -- Working files on Raid 1, then once disks are full on the Raid, perform a complete copy to two different regular drives (not raid, just a regular copy and paste). This is so I can have one drive on-site and one off-site in which could be accessible as regular disk without the need for dependency on each?

Comment: Yes, but I would.not wait until the disks are full. I'd get at least 2 additional drives, do regular backups and switch regularly so you always have 1 off-site.

Comment: Are there any software for Windows 10 that could do scheduled copy-paste to another drive? I believe MAC has this which is called time machine? Im looking into having what's on the RAID drive copied to 2 external drives on a scheduled basis. Like every midnight (12am) or so.

Comment: Im not a Windows person so I can't advise. There are definitely ways to schedule copies/backups though. You are probably not looking for "copy/paste" but scheduled backups. I'm also pretty sure Windows offers and equivalent continuous backup/sync to timemachine.

Answer (score 0):

It can work for some controllers.

The main requirement is to have RAID mode enabled instead of SATA mode for a correct read.

It works (tested) on controllers like AMD, Intel, LSI, even some more  professional ones like Dell. The reason it works is that the RAID information for such controllers is stored in on the disks themselves.

It is way less likely to work with secondary controllers like JMicron or Marwell.

So if you really want to try this, make sure you have a similar brand of controller (or even the same one - i.e. ICH9R) with RAID enabled.